# obligation-cordapp failed netty connection

Tags: corda

[image: failed netty connection]

I have this error when running PartyB in the obligation-cordapp from commandline in Windows. The PartyA has started properly and can make IOUs with PartyB, which is strange. Is this solved by restarting the corda-webserver? Is it possible to do this via the node's commandline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 10007 may already held by another process, preventing Netty from making a connection. Try identifying and killing the process holding the port.

Note that PartyB's web-server does not need to be working for PartyA to send it IOUs. Nodes do not use their web-servers to exchange messages.

You can start the corda-webserver directly by running it from the command line as follows: `java -jar corda-webserver.jar`.